# Tweetsharp - Getting lists for authenticated user

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

How can i get the lists for the authenticated user & the lists that user follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
    var service = new TwitterService();
    service.AuthenticateWith(<your consumerKey>, <your consumerSecret>, <your token>, <your tokensecret>);

    var listsUsersLists = service.ListListsFor(listOwnerScreenName);
    var listsUserIsIn = service.ListListMembershipsFor(listOwnerScreenName);
    var subscribedToLists = service.ListListSubscriptionsFor(subscriberName);
```

As long as the authenticated username is the same as the name of the lists you are trying to return, private lists will be included too.

Comment: thanks, i know that. I mentioned about getting "Twitter Lists" using tweet sharp , means getting list name & id

Comment: Thanks can i get it using fluenttwitter

Comment: I don't know - I've never used fluenttwitter.

Comment: i got it, FluentTwitter.CreateRequest().AuthenticateAs(username, password).Lists().GetListsBy(screenname).AsJson().Request().AsLists().ToList() i didnt notice it before you told using service.. thank you

Comment: Watch out, as Twitter are phasing out authentication with a username and password on August 16th and will only be accepting OAuth as their authentication method. Probably best to code that in now, rather than change it very soon.